Markdown to Pandoc then to word with tables
I'm struggling a little with this. I want to get a table from markdown parse it with pandoc and then get it into word with formatting on the table.



Heading 1
Heading 2
Heading 3




col 1
col 2
col 3



I have some text in markdown like this. I have extracted the template from pandoc with
pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx
Then I try to modify the basic Table format which word doesn't like because Table you cannot modify.
So how do I tell pandoc to use a different table structure I just want to get it some nice formatting in word.
pandoc -s -f markdown -t docx --reference-doc=custom-reference.docx inputmarkdown.md -o outputword.docx
Please can somebody help me really struggling.
Regards,
Marc
I didn't get any formatting on the table it's quite basic on the standard "Table" formatting

yes, that should work. what do you mean with "because Table you cannot modify"? you'll need to be more specific what's not working and what exactly you mean with "some nice formatting". finally, if the output format doesn't have to be word, you have lots more options.

Pandoc uses a table in the word document and word wouldn't let me edit the table style. So I couldn't change the style of the table. But I recreated the custom-reference.docx file again. Now it's let me change it and it all works. Thanks.

I think I understand what you mean. I've just spent quite a bit of time solving the problem!
As far as I can tell, the trick is to create your custom-reference.docx in Word, including a table that is formatted in the way you want all of your tables to be formatted.
Then, you need to save a Table Style based on the style of that table, and call that style "Table". To do this, go into the "Table Design" tab, right click in one of the standard styles, and click "New Table Style".
